# Jquery change color condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone I have an issue with Jquery :

I have a multiple selection and the user can select one thing and it will copy the text into an input above. I would like that the text in the multiple selection that will be copied become red if the button is clicked so did you understand? I don't know how to do condition in Jquery, here is what I have done :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    if ($choose = true)
    {
        $("ok").click(function(){
        $("droite").css({"background-color":"yellow"});
    }
    });
});
```

`droite` is an id and no it's not working but I would like to know how it works

choose is a function here it is :

```
     var choose = function(bouton){
    var lesoptions = $('#droite').find(":selected");
        //lesoptions.remove();
        $('#numLot').val(lesoptions[0].text);
};
```

Can I have your opinion ?

thanks

Comment: What is `droite`? id or class? Add `.droite` for class and `#droite` for id...

Comment: And does this work for you? `if ($choose = true)` this seems wrong to me...

Comment: sorry about that droite is an id and no it's not working  but i would like to know how does it work

Comment: And where is $choose? Is it defined?

Comment: May I guess you're missing the # in the jquery selector (if you are selecting them by Id) $('#ok') and $('#droite'). And obviously as it's commented you should have choose defined

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.` selector before class names and `#` before id names.

Read about selectors: **[jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

Since `choose` is a function so, you will have to return something and check if it returns true/false. So make your function like this:

```
function choose(bouton){
    var something = /*your return value*/; //Put your return value here
    var lesoptions = $('#droite').find(":selected");
    $('#numLot').val(lesoptions[0].text);
    return something; //something is what you want to be returned by function
};
```

If `$choose` is not defined while you are putting it in if condition then you will not get proper working.

If `#ok` is added dynamically then use `delegation` using `.on`.

You should put code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $choose = choose(bouton);
    if ($choose)
    {
        $("#ok").on("click",function(){ //Again not mentioned what is ok, still like you told I assume it id
            $("#droite").css("background-color","yellow");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: $ choose is a function a edited my post here is the function : var choose = function(bouton){
  var lesoptions = $('#droite').find(":selected");
   //lesoptions.remove();
   $('#numLot').val(lesoptions[0].text);
 };                                                                           and ok is an id so is droite

Comment: @Ynajar : Now have you been left with any more problems?

Comment: yes j809 it tell me that choose is not define i should something like var $choose = choose(bouton); or not ?

Comment: i already edited the function thanks but it's weird it tell me that "bouton" is not defined whereas bouton is an option

Comment: @Ynajar : No but `bouton` must be defined while calling the function... Does it work then?

Comment: i edited my code to be proper than before and i change the color automaticaly in the choose function here is the code :                            var choose = function(bouton){
 var retour = true;
  var lesoptions = $('#droite').find(":selected");
   //lesoptions.remove();
   $('#numLot').val(lesoptions[0].text);
   $("#ok").click(function(){
   $("#droite").css({"background-color":"yellow"});
   })
   };            i don't have any mistake but it won't do it

Comment: I suppose you are having more problems... Start a new question for that and end this question here by accepting the answer...

Answer (score 1):

$("ok") is wrong. it should be $("#ok") or $(".ok") or whatever.

compare operator is == instead =

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like below,

```
 var $Choose;
    //Assign value to $Choose as like true or false
      $(document).ready(function(){
            if ($choose)
            {
//If you have id like ok use "#" or if class use "." instead
                $("#ok").click(function(){
                    $("#droite").css({"background-color":"yellow"});
                });
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps...